# Problema ao conectar com o banco de dados SQL Server 2012 no IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Não consigo executar as consultas do meu sistema no IIS, quando executo no Visual Studio consigo obter o resultado tranquilamente.

O erro que recebo ao tentar fazer algo é o seguinte:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error
>   occurred while getting provider information from the database. This
>   can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection
>   string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the
>   connection string is correct. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Erro de rede ou específico
>   à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O
>   servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível.
>   Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL
>   Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de
>   Local Database Runtime. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the
>   Windows Application event log for error details. )

**EDIT**

Essa é a minha connection string:

```
<add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\V11.0;Initial Catalog=HomeAutomexdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Caso precise de mais informações, por favor, só avisar.

Comment: Você habilitou a comunicação por TCP/IP no SQL Server pelo SQL Server Configuration? Se puder postar sua connectionString seria bom, só mudar usuário e senha para algo como ***, e alterar o que mais não quiser que seja mostrado com o nome correto, mudando assim para um nome "falso".

Comment: No SQL Server Configuration o TCP/IP tá habilitado. Adicionei a connection string

Comment: Ok, então acredito que o seu problema seja o usuário, já que está Security Integrated. Experimente testar colocando um usuário e senha. Exemplo: `connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\V11.0; Initial Catalog=HomeAutomexdb; User Id=Administrator; Password=123456"`.

Comment: Outra coisa, porque desse `(localdb)`? Tente mudando apenas para `(local)\V11.0`, ou com o nome da instância também: `(local)\MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: O nome do servidor também: `Data Source=SERVIDOR\MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: No SQL Server 2012 só consegui logar no banco local utilizando o nome do servidor dessa forma aí. Trocando pra local não consigo conectar.

Comment: Não conseguiu setando um nome de usuário e senha?

Comment: Não tentei, estava utilizando a autenticação do windows mesmo

Comment: O problema com autenticacao do windows no contexto de IIS e que nao es 'tu', como num applicacao do console ou na Visual Studio local, mas e o servico ou windows account do Application Pool de baixo de qual o site foi configurado no IIS. Para um teste rapido, podes configurar o Application Pool Identity com o teu windows account...mas qualquer outro senario precisa dum 'service account' ou outra sistema de authorizar os credenciais do usuario.

Answer (score 4):

**A porta 1433 está liberada no firewall do server que tem o banco?**

Caso não esteja execute os passos já respondido aqui nessa página por outro usuário.

**O banco está no mesmo servidor que o site?**

Se não estiver, execute esses passos abaixo, pois na sua connectionstring está LOCAL, e ai temos a necessidade de colocar o nome do server que está o banco.

São 8 passos super simples, acredito que com isso não terá erro, e se ocorrer terá como printar e colocar aqui para discutirmos sobre, porque dessa maneira será mais fácil de mapear onde está o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: essa é uma bela forma de montar a connectionstring, +1 pela criatividade

Answer (score 3):

Veja se isso pode resolver o seu problema.

Retirado do site: [angmaximo.wordpress.com](http://angmaximo.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/configurando-portas-tcp/)

Abra a console do SQL Server Configuration Manager e vá na seção SQL Server Network
Configuration:

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

Em `Protocols for MSSQLSERVER`, ou `Protocols for SQLEXPRESS` conforme a sua versão, verifique se a opção TCP/IP está habilitada conforme a figura mostra.
`TCP/IP   Enabled`

Então clique o botão direito do mouse sobre ele e selecione `Enable`.

Por padrão o SQL Server é instalado com a porta 1433, verifique isso clicando com o direito do mouse sobre TCP/IP e selecione a opção `Properties` (`Propriedades`).

[image: Configurações TCP/IP]

Na aba IP Addresses, você verá que existem várias referências a endereços IP (IP1, IP2 até IPALL), e para cada IP, há 2 campos: TCP Dynamic Ports e TCP Port. TCP Dynamic Ports com valor 0 indica que o SQL Server irá escutar por portas dinâmicas, e em TCP Port será fixado um valor de porta;

Então, pelo padrão, verifique se está com **1433** as opções `TCP Port`, a não ser que precise de outro número de porta.

Feito isso é só clicar em OK, então você provavelmente conseguira acessar.